# Mongo DB 2.0.1 issue

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have an issue with MongoDB version 2.0.1. I have installed it on an Ubuntu
machine that is 32 bit. I am able to connect to it through the command
prompt, but not able to connect to it through Java code. This same code
used to work with the older MongoDB version. I get the following
exception.

```
    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBPort.findOne failed
       at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:153)
       at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:159)
       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.testMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:369)
       at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:140)
       at
com..bean.MongoCollectionPoolBean.init(MongoCollectionPoolBean.java:
42)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
57)
       at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
       at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
1544)
       at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
1485)
       at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
1417)
       ... 24 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to
    [domU-12-31-39-0B-26-01/67.265.65.132:27017]
    bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
           at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:205)
           at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:85)
           at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:145)
           ... 35 more
```

When I try to reproduce the same problem with my local system (Mac Lion
    64 bit) it works fine. When I see the server logs here is what i see on
    my local system:

[clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:14 virt:2434 mapped:0

and on Ubuntu (where it is not working)

[clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:14 virt:86 mapped:0

Comment: Are you sure the IP address of the MongoDB server (67.265.65.132) is correct? Do you have a firewall running that blocks network traffic?

Comment: it is on local host and yes this is correct

Comment: I'm not a Java guy, but the common idea would dictate that perhaps the driver needs to be updated as well?  Can you check if your current package for MongoDB is compatible with the upgrade you ran on the server?

Comment: If it is on localhost, then use 127.0.0.1 instead of some other IP address; then you can save an unnecessary trip through the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

if your application is connecting to mongodb on the same box, then use 127.0.0.1 so that it doesnt break when your amazon instance change IP addresses.
In general it is better to use a hostname that you point to an IP via /etc/hosts or dns.
If this still does not work make sure you can do "telnet localhost 27017" from the local terminal.
If it cannot connect then either mongodb is not running on that port, or you have a firewall.